# Unable to output MySQL tables which involve dates in Sequel

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, sequel

I'm trying to use Sequel to access a MySQL database in Ruby. When I try accessing a table which involves a date column, I am presented with an error. When I access a table without, it functions fine. What is wrong?

#### Example Code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.connect(:adapter=>'mysql', :host=>'localhost', :database=>'db', :user=>'user', :password=>'password')

event = DB[:table]

puts event.all
```

#### Error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:956:in `new_by_frags': ArgumentError: invalid date (Sequel::InvalidValue)
```

The error is not shown when a table which does not feature a date is accessed. This is running on Debian.

Comment: sounds as though you need to tell ruby/sequel that it is talking to MySQL. Apparently the value it receives for a 'date' looks different from what is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  It was caused by Sequel choking on MySQL's zero date ‘0000-00-00’.  The solution I used was to set

```
Sequel::MySQL.convert_invalid_date_time = nil
```

(found here: http://groups.google.com/group/sequel-talk/browse_thread/thread/152a4131bd280966).

If you control the DB, you could also prevent MySQL storing zero dates using the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date.

Comment: As @andrewpurcell points out this no longer works. Use `DB.convert_invalid_date_time = nil` instead. See [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9356325/186424)

Answer (score 3):

Heads up:

```
Sequel::MySQL.convert_invalid_date_time = nil
```

no longer works, but I just fixed this same problem by setting the option on my DB object:

```
DB = Sequel.connect("mysql://localhost/#{DB_NAME}")
DB.convert_invalid_date_time = nil
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

The final solution involved switching to use the data_objects Ruby gem. This avoided issues using the native C MySQL driver.

The code is adjusted as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sequel'

# connect to the db
DB = Sequel.connect('do:mysql://user:pass@localhost/database')
```

Possibly this could cause performance issues, but this is beyond the scope of my initial issue.

*Thanks to lexu for commenting on the original question.*

Comment: That's probably because DataObjects does the typecasting internally in the do_mysql C extension, while when using the regular MySQL adapter, Sequel is doing the typecasting using Date.parse, which apparently can't handle whatever date format your MySQL database is providing.